# As a Kubernetes admin, what is the best way to handle user authentication for kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way, as a Kubernetes admin, to make users and give them access to `kubectl`. Originally, I was going to use serviceAccounts, but it seems that that should not be used as authentication for users. I have been reading over this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#users-in-kubernetes but there are so many different ways to authenticate I was not sure what the best practices are for my use case. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using OpenID Connect Authentication using Google. I followed this guide to set it up: https://www.skuid.com/blog/reduce-administrative-toil-with-kubernetes-1-3/.

Answer (score 2):

i would go the cert route.  I believe that what most people use for production and its what we currently use.  I included a link to the hard way which has a better description on making certs.

https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/02-certificate-authority.md

good luck